# Providing Count from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output a count of the number of results I have in a survey. The query itself ($sql) seems correct, because I do not get the error I have included, when I know that works. What isn't happening is the output. I have all my PHP tags and my database connection in place just fine, so I haven't included them here. They function just fine. What I need to know is how to get this outputted. This echoing for a count had worked for a previous PHP database set, but it is not working for this one.

My database has just ONE table, named survey. 'sur_cnt' is an auto-increment field that adds up whenever a new input is added to the database. My page output comes out blank, so I believe something is wrong with the echo, but I'm not sure what.

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`sur_cnt`) FROM Survey";
 $num = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Error 
      querying database.');
 $num_results = $result->num_rows ;
 echo $num_results ;
```

Comment: `$num = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Error 
      querying database.');` should be `$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Error 
      querying database.');`

Comment: Your query returns 1 row. If you want to access the value of count(whatever) then you need to give it an alias and then reference that alias.

Comment: That got me A result, but not the correct one. It provided me with "1" as the output, when it should have been "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

because `COUNT()` using with `groub by cluase`

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Survey"; //remove count()
 $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');
 $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result) ;
 echo $num_results ;
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you than accept the answer so other will easily find it

Comment: I'm trying, but the platform is making me wait a certain amount of time before I CAN accept it.

Comment: This would mean that you have to retrieve every single row in the database just to count them. Also you don't need a GROUP BY clause to just count all of the rows, only if you wanted them to be split by some other columns.

Comment: @NigelRen I didn't include the group by, just the rest of the code in the box. It just gave me the count output, nothing more.

Comment: Although you will not see all of the rows being retrieved, the database will have to fetch all of the data.  If you have 3 rows not so much of a problem, but if you have 1,000,000 rows, then it will still need to fetch the data for all of these rows.  The problem with some code is that it looks fine, but you need to understand what is happening when the code is run.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for the advise but if no more data so its ok or no

Comment: If you have time, have a go with this solution with a large number of rows and see how it gets on.

Comment: I'm only going to have 10 rows for this particular need; but I will definitely keep what you said in mind should I need a bigger database Nigel, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some form of fetch method to actually retrieve the count from your SQL statement - just the same as any other type of data from the database...

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`sur_cnt`) FROM Survey";
 $num = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($num) ;
 echo $row[0] ;
```